# What's up with this font?

Tags: fonts

What kind of font does this text use:

It doesn't appear anywhere in the Windows Fonts folder... It's a really strange font and I want to find out where the location of this font is stored.

Comment: How did you come across this font? The text posted is in Unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text consists of letters in the Unicode [Math_Alphanum](https://codepoints.net/search?blk=Math_Alphanum) block (e.g.  [U+1D683](https://codepoints.net/U+1D683)). It is rendered using a separate area of your regular fonts.